# Linker Error: LNK1181 while attempting to compile with FMOD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fmod

this is a problem that has been bugging me for a bit with my current project, and I haven't quite been able to figure it out. I'm making a game within a team, and the member who has been working on our FMOD implementation installed FMOD on his computer. When he runs the project on his system, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to run it on mine, I get LNK1181 constantly. I've tried setting up my include and library folders in my VS2012 so that it references the folder with all of the .h, .hpp, .lib, and .dll files in it, but I still get 1181. In addition, I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution many, many times and it doesn't do anything. I also tried using `#pragma comment(lib, "FMOD/fmodex_vc.lib")` but it didn't help. This is the output from the linker:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/LTCG' specification
1>  
1>  Starting pass 1
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:FMOD/fmodex_vc.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
1>Audio.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:msvcprtd
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\lib\fmodex_vc.lib'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does ..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Windows\api\lib\fmodex_vc.lib exist?

Comment: The file exists, in the location that I specified for it to look, but that path is completely non-existent. My teammate has that folder, though. That's the main reason we're having this problem, he didn't think ahead when he was setting up FMOD for our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add fmodex_vc.lib file in the linker settings in Visual Studio.

Compare your setup, VS version, FMOD version, Platfrom SDK, etc etc.

Remove lib references and rebuild. Create a dir inside project dir and add lib file there, then reference it from there.

Make sure you use the same FMOD lib file.

Comment: I ended up needing to completely restructure my project, there was some arcane issue that was causing problems. I got it working now, thanks!